# Inequality $\iint_{\mathcal{C}} |g(h)|dxdh \leq 2|\mbox{supp}(f)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|g(h)|dh$ it's true?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f, g \in C^2_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be and define the set
$$\mathcal{C} := \left\{(x,h) \in \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N \mid x \ \mbox{or} \ x + h \in \mbox{supp}(f)\right\}.$$
Inequality
$$\iint_{\mathcal{C}} |g(h)|dxdh \leq 2|\mbox{supp}(f)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|g(h)|dh$$
it's true?

Note: I looked for an approach writing
$$\mathcal{C} := \left(\mbox{supp}(f) \times \mathbb{R}^N\right) \cup \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} \{x\} \times \mbox{supp}(f - x),$$
but I didn't get anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its true. You can indeed cut the integral in the union of two sets $\mathcal{C}_0$ and $\mathcal{C}_1$ with $\mathcal{C}_0 = \mathrm{supp}(f)\times\Bbb R^d$ and $\mathcal{C}_1 := \left\{(x,h) \in \Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R^d \mid  x + h \in \mathrm{supp}(f)\right\}$. On the first set you get by Fubini
$$
\iint_{\mathcal{C}_0} |g| = |\mathrm{supp}(f)| \int_{\Bbb R^d} |g|
$$
On the second one, you can do the change of variable $y=x+h$ to get
$$
\iint_{\mathcal{C}_1} |g(h)| \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d h =  \iint_{\Bbb R^{2d}} |g(h)| \,\mathbf{1}_{\mathrm{supp} f}(x+h) \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d h
\\
= \iint_{\Bbb R^{2d}} |g(h)| \,\mathbf{1}_{\mathrm{supp}(f)}(y) \,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d h = |\mathrm{supp}(f)| \int_{\Bbb R^d} |g|.
$$
The inequality then follows from $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}_0\cup \mathcal{C}_1$